# How to fix Error json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

My project get bus ticket time information from api. But it don't show going time if there is no data for return time from server. This is the error message when I send request by Volley.

> Error json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

code  snippet

```
private void sendRequest(final String owner, final Map<String, String> header) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MyConstants.URL + owner,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                 //   Log.e("AAAA" + owner, response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_NOTAVAILABLE)) {
                            // servisten gelen cevap not_available ise
                            //// owner
                            sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NOTAVAILABLE);
                        } else if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                            JSONArray result = object.getJSONArray(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESULT);
                            JSONArray resultGoing = result.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("going");
                            if (has_return) {
                                JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round");
                                sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_RETURN, resultReturn);
                            }
                            sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_GOING, resultGoing);
                        } else if (object.getString(MyConstants.SERVICE_STATUS).equals(MyConstants.SERVICE_RESPONSE_STATUS_FAİLURE)) {
                            sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_SERVER);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("search" + owner + "VoyagesErr1", e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please paste complete exception stack trace, and the code snippet where it is throwing exception, It is possible because your result array has size 1 and you are iterating over more than once

Comment: Have a look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073428/how-to-solve-org-json-jsonexception-index-0-out-of-range-0-0-using-android?rq=1

Comment: What is your `JSON`? You want to get object on index `1` but there is no such element in array. See this line: `result.getJSONObject(1)`.

Comment: @Ravi thats the strack trace https://i.hizliresim.com/Ll59oz.jpg

Comment: @MichałZiober yes there is no element in this index. This index show if there is return bus. But in this situation there is going bus and there is no return bus. So it get this error.

Comment: @Shayma, so you need to check array size before using index. What the library do you use and in which version to read `JSON` (`JSONArray`, `JSONObject` classes).

Comment: @MichałZiober I am trying this but it doesn't step resultReturn.length. `if (has_return)  {
                                    JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round");
                                        if (resultReturn.length() > 0) {
                                    sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_RETURN, resultReturn);}
                          //         } else{sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast(owner, MyConstants.ERROR_NOTAVAILABLE);}
                                }`

Comment: To help you I need to know how `JSON` payload looks like when you have an error and what library do you use and in which version.

Comment: i guess this line is giving you the error as you are trying to access the element at index 1 which does not exist , resultReturn =  result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round") additionally the index in json starts from 0 hence even if the size is 1 it will give u a error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code

```
 if (has_return) {
     JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round");
     sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_RETURN, resultReturn);
  }
```

You are trying to access the element at index 1, which is probably not present. Index starts from 0 not 1 and hence even if the result json array size is 1 it will give an error

try to do something like this

```
if (has_return) {
    if (result.length() > 1)
        JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("round");
        sendVoyagesArrayBroadcast(owner + MyConstants.DIRECTION_RETURN, resultReturn);
    }
}
```

or else if you are interested in first element then access it like

```
if (result.length() > 0) {
    JSONArray resultReturn = result.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("round");
}
```

Comment: Yes this work for check array size. But I have another problem now. If resultGoing is not null sendVoyagesBroadcast must work, else sendVoyagesErrorBroadcast must work. That must work same for resultReturn also. I can't do truth code for it.

Comment: what should be the data passed in that case, your point is not clear to me

Comment: If this solves the question you asked, Please mark this as accepted and ask a new question, we would love to answer that

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: @Shayma Can you describe the problem you are facing now or the link of the new question you asked

Comment: I am trying to solve it. If I can't solve I will post that as new question.